# Delete command in SQL

Tags: sql-delete

I want to delete 10 rows from access data

```
Oledbcommand cmd = new oledbcommand("Delete Top 10 From [Log], cnn);
cnn. Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I have Syntax error in DELETE statement

Comment: What is your database?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax seems fine for SQL Server. (I assume you use SQL Server, because you use brackets for delimiting table or view `Log`. Sorry if I'm wrong...)

I think you got the error, because you forgot a closing quote for the SQL statement in your OleDbCommand constructor. And casing is sensitive in C#. You could try this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Delete Top 10 From [Log]", cnn);
```

If you get a SQL related error, my assumption might be wrong and you need to look up the specific SQL syntax for the database system that you are using.

Tip: If you are using SQL Server, you may also look into the specialized `SqlCommand` class and corresponding classes in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. They offer additional support for SQL Server functionality.